# Perturbation Matrix Eigenvalues and Power Series

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

From Richard Bellman's *Introduction to Matrix Analysis*,

> Let $\lambda_i$ denote the characteristic roots of $A$ and $\lambda_i(z)$ those of $A+zB$. Show that
> $$\lambda_j(A+zB)=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \lambda_j(m) z^m$$
> such that $\lambda_j(0)=\lambda_j$ and
> $$\lambda_j(m)=(-1)^m m^{-1}tr\left(\sum\limits_{k_1+\cdots + k_m = m-1 \\ \;\;\;\;\;\;k_i\geq 0} BS_j^{k_1}BS_j^{k_2}\cdots BS_j^{k_m}\right)$$
> where $S_j = -E_j$, $A=\sum\limits_j \lambda_j E_j$, and $S_j = \sum\limits_{k\neq j} \frac{E_k}{\lambda_k - \lambda_j}$.

**My Attempt/Question**: We know that for $t>0$,

$$S_j^t=\sum\limits_{k\neq j} \frac{E_j}{(\lambda_k - \lambda_j)^t}$$

as the cross terms vanish by orthogonality ($E_iE_j=0$ for $i\neq j$) and $E_j$ are idempotent ($E_i^2=E_i$) by construction (spectral decomposition of $A$). Additionally, it seems like it might be fruitful to use the fact that the sum of eigenvalues is equal to the trace of a matrix, but I'm not sure what matrix is represented by the sum of that product of matrices $BS_j^{k_l}$. It's also possible I miswrote/interpreted the question - any help would be appreciated as I'm stumped.